# differentiate tags text-editors text-editing and text-manipulation, add automated-text-manipulation

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Currently, questions tagged as text-editing fall in two categories: 1. with visual text editors,  2. with parametrised programmes.

I here suggest the removal of the text-editing tag. More questions are already dual-tagged as text-editors, while other questions get re-tagged as (previously non-existent) automated-text-manipulation.

There is also a text-manipulation tag (not popular). That tag is still ambiguous.

Comment: There are a ton of tags for specific applications, but generic tags: [text-editors] (535) and synonomized [text-editor], [text-editing] (306), [plaintext] (48) looks like includes some overlap and no wiki, [text-manipulation] (22) with no wiki, and [text-processors] (8) also no wiki.  Are you looking to distinguish editors used for text (i.e., normal language without fancy formatting) vs. editors used for code or things like OS configuration files?  By automated text manipulation, are you referring to regex?  Not sure I'm completely understanding where you want to go with this.